# Not equal expression

Tags: reporting-services, equals, ssrs-expression

I'm looking at using 4 expressions 3 being equals and 1 being not equals but is not counting the not equals

im using .

```
=sum(iif(Fields!NEW_SUPPLIER.Value = "Eon", 1,0) 
And (Fields!WeekDay.Value = "Monday")
And (Fields!UTILITY.Value = "Elec")
And (Fields!OLD_SUPPLIER.Value <> "Eon"))
```

Please can some one point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure all the checks are in the first argument of the `IIf` expression:

```
=sum
(
  iif
    (
        Fields!NEW_SUPPLIER.Value = "Eon"
            And Fields!WeekDay.Value = "Monday"
            And Fields!UTILITY.Value = "Elec"
            And Fields!OLD_SUPPLIER.Value <> "Eon"
        ,1
        ,0
    )
)
```